# TensorFlow/Keras: How to get missing models (ResNet101, ResNeXt, etc.) from Keras' applications module?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, python-module

A number of documented [Keras applications](https://keras.io/applications/) are missing from my (up-to-date) Keras installation and TensorFlow 1.10 Keras API installation.
I import Keras' applications module as suggested and use it as follows:

```
from keras import applications
resnet = applications.ResNeXt101(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(SCALED_HEIGHT, SCALED_WIDTH, 3), pooling=None)
```

I also tried

```
resnet = applications.resnext.ResNeXt101(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(SCALED_HEIGHT, SCALED_WIDTH, 3), pooling=None)
```

But in both cases I get the same type of error:

```
AttributeError: module 'keras.applications' has no attribute 'ResNeXt101'
```

Printing `help(applications)` yields:

```
Help on package keras.applications in keras:

NAME
    keras.applications

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    densenet
    imagenet_utils
    inception_resnet_v2
    inception_v3
    mobilenet
    mobilenet_v2
    mobilenetv2
    nasnet
    resnet50
    vgg16
    vgg19
    xception

FUNCTIONS
    DenseNet121 = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    DenseNet169 = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    DenseNet201 = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    InceptionResNetV2 = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    InceptionV3 = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    MobileNet = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    MobileNetV2 = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    NASNetLarge = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    NASNetMobile = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    ResNet50 = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    VGG16 = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    VGG19 = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    Xception = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    keras_modules_injection(base_fun)
```

which shows that the models initially aren't present in my installation. Why not? They're also not packaged in the TensorFlow's Keras API.

I tried copying the files from the [Keras applications GitHub repository](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/tree/master/keras_applications) and pasting them in `site-packages/keras/applications/`, but this results in the following stacktrace:

```
File "myscript.py", line 517, in get_fpn
    resnet = applications.resnext.ResNeXt101(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(SCALED_HEIGHT, SCALED_WIDTH, 3), pooling=None)
  File "site-packages/keras/applications/resnet_common.py", line 575, in ResNeXt101
    **kwargs)
  File "site-packages/keras/applications/resnet_common.py", line 348, in ResNet
    data_format=backend.image_data_format(),
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'image_data_format'
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Why aren't these included and working in default installations of either Keras or TensorFlow? Why does the documentation not explain this?

Comment: I see that you are deleting and reposting your question, you should not do that.

Comment: Yeah I know its not okay, but me and future people with the same problem did get a good answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Reason for the problem:**

The `backend` object is `None` at line 348.
My guess is you tried something like this:

```
>>> from keras_applications import resnext
>>> resnext.ResNeXt101(weights=None)
```

The `backend` information is injected from keras.applications to keras_applications via the `keras_modules_injection` decorator.

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/c658993cf596fbd39cf800873bc457e69cfb0cdb/keras/applications/resnext.py#L17

- **Procedure to fix the problem:**

Make sure the keras & keras applications versions are as follows:

```
>>pip list |grep Keras
Keras                  2.2.4
Keras-Applications     1.0.8
```

If they're not, upgrade using

```
>>pip install --upgrade keras keras-applications
```

Update the changes from this pull request, https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/11203/files into `site-packages/keras/applications`

```
from keras import applications
resnext = applications.resnext.ResNeXt101(include_top=False, weights=None, input_shape=(299,299,3))
print(type(resnext))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I merged the pull request by adding the necessary lines and commenting out newer lines which do the same thing, but I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'keras_modules_injection'` on the line `from . import keras_modules_injection`. I assume because `keras_modules_injection` does not exist. And why should I need to merge the pull request when the pull request was already merged with the main branch (I assume a long time ago, since the code of the associated files looks different now).

Comment: If you're using the master branch it is not required. If you're using 2.2.4 version then the merge is required.

Comment: Please check your merge again. Maybe something got overwritten in \_\_init__.py. keras_modules_injection is present in https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.2.4/keras/applications/__init__.py

Comment: Hmm I don´t think I overwrote anything, but I simply reinstalled from master and now I get further (even though they are they have the same version number, so I don´t really get it). Many thanks! Now I get `RuntimeError: tf.placeholder() is not compatible with eager execution.` in `"tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1732, in placeholder` upon calling `applications.resnext.ResNeXt101()`, but I guess that´s an unrelated issue, and not something I´ll be capable enough to fix.

Comment: How do I update the changes from the pull request? I did the `conda install -c anaconda keras-gpu` command, what should I run next?